# Does both ContentProvider and ContentResolver application need to be in memory to communicate?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Does both ContentProvider and ContentResolver application need to be in memory to communicate?

**Two applications are different** and using permission to read and write.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. However, if an app makes a request using a `ContentResolver`, and the provider's app is not running, Android will start up a process for that app to create the provider, to be able to respond to the request. So, by the time the communication completes, both processes will be running.